How can I search for all tables with at least one tag template attached across all BigQuery datasets in a project using Google Data Catalog?
I want to do this in Python and I am currently trying with this code:
def get_tables_with_tags(project_id):
    scope = {'include_project_ids': [project_id]}
    search_query = 'type=TABLE AND tag:x'
    search_request = datacatalog_v1.SearchCatalogRequest(scope=scope, query=search_query)
    results = datacatalog_client.search_catalog(request=search_request)

    tables_with_tags = set()
    for result in results:
        if result.linked_resource.startswith('//bigquery.googleapis.com/'):
            resource_parts = result.linked_resource.split('/')
            project = resource_parts[4]
            dataset = resource_parts[6]
            table_id = resource_parts[8]
            tables_with_tags.add(f'{project}.{dataset}.{table_id}')
    
    return tables_with_tags

but it is returning an empty set.
I also tried to set search_query = 'type=TABLE has:tags' (as suggested by ChatGPT) but it also returns an empty set, even though I know there are at least two tables with a tag template attached.
I also tried only search_query = 'type=TABLE' and it actually returns a full list of all tables across all datasets in the project. So I am not sure if it is allowed to set two different predicates inside the query of the SearchCatalogRequest, according to the Search Sintax.
Or could it be that I don't have enough permissions to list all tagged tables?
Do you have any suggestion on how to achieve this? I am not experienced in Google Cloud Data Catalog, so I might be missing something trivial. Thanks!
